# os.path.relpath not returning a relative path when using drive as start point

Tags: python, path

Why is `os.path.relpath`, on Windows, not returning the proper relative path when using a drive as the start point, either explicit or implied (current directory)

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'U:\\projects'
>>> os.path.relpath(r'D:\foo\something', r"D:\\")
'..\\foo\\something'
>>> os.chdir("D:\\")
>>> os.getcwd()
'd:\\'
>>> os.path.relpath(r'D:\foo\something')
'..\\foo\\something'    
>>> os.path.relpath(r'D:\foo\something', r"D:\\foo")
'something'
```

I was expecting to see

```
'foo\\something'
```

or

```
'.\\foo\\something'
```

Does it have anything to do with the os.path.join note on windows?

> Note that on Windows, since there is a
>   current directory for each drive,
>   os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a
>   path relative to the current directory
>   on drive

I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Issue is fixed](http://bugs.python.org/issue5117) under python 2.7.1

> Issue #5117: Fixed root directory
>   related issue on posixpath.relpath()
>   and   ntpath.relpath().